# Is there a way to call the `[<-` function in `[` form?

Tags: r, function

Let's assume that I am a lazy programmer with bad habits (who also happens to not know about plyr/dplyr), I like doing operations like this:

```
`[<-`((z<-reshape2::melt(iris)), z[,"value"]>5, 3, 100)
```

Melt `iris`, then assign the value 100 to the rows where the `value` is greater than 5, then return all the rows, not just the selected rows. This function is described on the page for `?"["`

The same code with `replace()` (well almost the same)

```
 z[,"value"] <- replace(i <- ((z <- reshape2::melt(iris))[,"value"]), i > 5, 100)
```

1) But the question is: is there a way to call the `[<-` function using the standard bracket notation `iris[<-, blah, blah, blah, ?]`?

edit July 2016: so the purpose of this question is NOT to replicate the operation. The data doesn't matter, the example doesn't matter, the convoluted way of reshaping the data doesn't matter.

Comment: You could define a function `\`[.myClass\` <- function(stuff) assign(stuff)` or something along those lines and then `class(iris) <- "myClass"`

Comment: ``[.myClass` <- function(...) `[<-`(...); class(iris) <- c("myClass", class(iris))`` or ``cake = function(...) `[<-`(...)`` are valid solutions but require function declarations, which is clearly against the wishes of a lazy programmer. Can't seem to get the leading ` to show up.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps the programmer should stop being so lazy and put in some work... haha :)

Comment: `\`[<-\`(z=reshape2::melt(iris),z[3]>5,3,100)` would be fewer keystrokes. I don't know why that matters at all. what does "function using using the standard.." mean? do you mean "without using?" If you are actually playing code golf that is one thing, but figuring out the fewest keystrokes you need to make to do something seems like an error-prone waste of time as well as making a script harder to debug since you are combining so many steps into one. this isn't saving a significant amount of time

Comment: I also have a hard time understanding why you are trying to cram so much stuff into an incomprehensible statement. My suggestion would be `within(reshape2::melt(iris), value[value > 5] <- 100)`.

Comment: `within` is an interesting function. I didn't realize `with`'s cousin can be used in such ways. I just figured that since `[<-` was on the help page for `extract`, there would be a way of calling it using the bracket notation. This was not an attempt at golfing, but `[<-` can be used for golfing.

Comment: @Vlo Can `[<-` be used successfully for golfing?

Comment: @Dason No, it is always 4 characters longer than `k[condition]=replacement.value;k` (compared to `"[<-"(i,condition,replacement.value)` which happens to the answer to this question. I just thought of the answer while writing this comment. Its only purpose right now is to write less maintainable code, which can be a good thing.

Comment: @Vlo That's what I thought so I wasn't sure what you meant with your comment.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dason When I posted this question, I initially thought it could be used for golfing. `pryr::f()` however is my new golfing best friend.

Comment: After thinking about this for another few weeks, what I posted above is incorrect. Still no answer.

Comment: what about iris[iris > 5] <- 100 ? I mean do you need the long format. In which case you should reformulate the problem using a long data frame as example.

Comment: I don't really get the point of this -- which seems to depend heavily on your amorphous conception of "laziness" -- but `library(data.table); melt(as.data.table(iris))[ value > 5, value := 100][]` works fine...

Comment: ``[<-`((z<-reshape2::melt(iris)), z[,"value"]>5, 3, 100)` this is the most black-voodo-magic looking R code I've seen in a while :). But I agree with @Frank that what is or is not laziness or ugly code is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question: ofcourse not. For

```
iris[<-, blah, blah, blah, ?]
```

to work, the `[` function should take another function (or operator) as a second argument, and `[` is a primitive that doesn't allow that.

You might argue "but the function is called `[<-`". It is not. If you write

```
x[i,j,...]
```

Then you call a function `[` with first argument `x`, second argument `i` and so forth. In your line of code, `i` is the function `<-`. The assignment operator is a function indeed:

```
> `<-`
.Primitive("<-")
> `<-`("x",1)
> x
[1] 1
```

So what you write in that line, boils down to:

```
`[`(iris, <-, blah, blah ... )
```

and that will give an error in R's interpreter; the assignment operator is interpreted as an attempt to assign something. This is clearly invalid code.

You might propose using backticks so it becomes:

```
iris[`<-`, blah, blah, ... ]
```

which translates to

```
`[`(iris, `<-`, blah, blah ,... )
```

but also that is something that is not and never will be allowed by the primitive `[`.

Some people suggested you could write your own method, and you can - for classes you defined yourself. But you can't redefine `[` itself to allow this for any generic data frame, unless you rewrite the R interpreter to recognize your construct as a call to `[<-` instead of `[`.